# Add a prefix/suffix to value of input tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have this situation: I need to add quotes inside an input text field (html) without changing the value of the input. I'm working with angular so I use ngModel, it looks like this

```html
<input ng-model="data" type="text" />
```

I want the input field to show "whatever is in `{{data}}`" but the variable data itself remains unchanged (no quotes).

I haven't found any css/Angular tricks yet... any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `ng-model="data"` in `<input type="text">` binds the `data` with *entire text field*. This is not particularly useful in situations where you want only a  portion of text(being displayed in text field) to get bind with the scope.

For instance, if you do

```
<input type="text" value="prefixText {{name}} suffixText" ng-model="name">
```

The input box will display whatever is in `name`(with no prefix/suffix text)

However, there's a workaround. Use `ng-bind` on the variable and mention prefix/suffix text separately in the `value="..."` attribute.

```
<input type="text" value="prefixText {{name}} suffixText" ng-bind="name">
```

Here's the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/CfHhJ6h539y9mSLqQNNn?p=preview)

Comment: is there a way to make the prefixText suffixText surround the text where I'm typing it?

Comment: The first text-box where you are typing is provided to *let user change* the `name` and see its effect in second text-box

Comment: I want all in one... i.e the pre/suffixes should surround the text as I type it. without changing {{data}}

Answer (score -2):

You can try this

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Telephone</mat-label>
    <span matPrefix>+1 &nbsp;</span>
    <input type="tel" matInput placeholder="555-555-1234">
    <mat-icon matSuffix>mode_edit</mat-icon>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

[Demo](https://run.stackblitz.com/api/angular/v1?file=src%2Fapp%2Finput-prefix-suffix-example.ts)

Comment: The question is about AngularJS (v1) and your answer is for Angular (v2+) also the demo link is broken.

Comment: In Question haven't mention the angular version Anyway it will work for Angular 2+

Comment: The tag mentions it because it's tagged with angularjs. And you clearly use the Material package created for Angular (v2+) so no, your answer won't work.

Comment: Thank you, @RizwanAli.  This was a Google search result specifically for Angular 12 and was helpful to me (despite the question being for AngularJS v1.x).